# Auth:check() always returns false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I tried googling but didn't get the solution yet.

I'm trying to  know whether user is authenticated or not into the view file by using

1. `Auth::check()` always returns `false`
2. `Auth::User()` always returns `NULL`

Tried posts:

1. [It says to place domain to null that's already there.](https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/11-11-2014-authcheck-always-returning-false)
2. Some posts say to edit into the kernel.php, how safe is it?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please paste a snippet of the code where you login the User